# send buttons values from one activity to another

Tags: android

I created two activities (MainSecond.java) which contents my 2 buttons and (SegmentBitmapsLoader.java)that contents my segmentation model what I want to make is : when I click on button1 it sends button id to (SegmentBitmapsLoader.java) and then initialize model1 and the same thing with button2 and model2 the problem is : when I tried to use getIntent().getStringExtra(); in the (SegmentBitmapsLoader.java) it gives me error because this class doesn't extend Activity what should I do ?

**(MainSecond.java)**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_main);


    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BackToMain2(view);
        }
    });

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            BackToMain2(view);

        }

    });
}



 public void BackToMain2(View view) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainSecond.this, SegmentBitmapsLoader.class);
    intent2.putExtra("name","button1");
    intent2.putExtra("name","button2");
    startActivity(intent2);

}
```

}

**SegmentBitmapsLoader.java**

```
public class SegmentBitmapsLoader extends AbsAsyncDataLoader<List<SegmentBitmap>> {

    private Uri mImageUri;

    public SegmentBitmapsLoader(Context context, Uri imageUri) {
        super(context);

        mImageUri = imageUri;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override

    public List<SegmentBitmap> loadInBackground() {
        final Context context = getContext();

        if (context == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final Resources res = context.getResources();

        if (res == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (mImageUri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final String filePath = FilePickUtils.getPath(context, mImageUri);
        Logger.debug("file to mask: %s", filePath);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
            return null;
        }

        boolean vertical = checkAndReportDimen(filePath);

        final int dw = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
                vertical ? R.dimen.image_width_v : R.dimen.image_width_h);
        final int dh = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
                vertical ? R.dimen.image_height_v : R.dimen.image_height_h);
        Logger.debug("display image dimen: [%d x %d]", dw, dh);

        Bitmap bitmap = decodeBitmapFromFile(filePath, dw, dh);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<SegmentBitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();

        bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_original, bitmap));//important note

        final int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        final int h = bitmap.getHeight();
        Logger.debug("decoded file dimen: [%d x %d]", w, h);

        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ImageDimenEvent(mImageUri, w, h));

        float resizeRatio = (float) DeeplabModel.INPUT_SIZE / Math.max(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        float resizeRatio2 = (float) DeeplabModel2.INPUT_SIZE / Math.max(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());


        int rw = Math.round(w * resizeRatio);
        int rh = Math.round(h * resizeRatio);

        int rw2 = Math.round(w * resizeRatio2);
        int rh2 = Math.round(h * resizeRatio2);

        Logger.debug("resize bitmap: ratio = %f, [%d x %d] -> [%d x %d]",
                resizeRatio, w, h, rw, rh);
        Logger.debug("resize bitmap: ratio = %f, [%d x %d] -> [%d x %d]",
                resizeRatio2, w, h, rw2, rh2);

        Bitmap resized = ImageUtils.tfResizeBilinear(bitmap, rw, rh);
        Bitmap resized2 = ImageUtils.tfResizeBilinear(bitmap, rw2, rh2);


        Bitmap mask = DeeplabModel.segment(resized);
        Bitmap mask2 = DeeplabModel2.segment(resized2);


        if (mask != null) {
            mask = BitmapUtils.scaleBitmap(mask, w, h);
            bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, mask));

            final Bitmap cropped = cropBitmapWithMask(bitmap, mask);
            bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, cropped));
        } else {
            bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, (Bitmap) null));
            bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, (Bitmap) null));
        }
    if(mask2 != null){
        mask2 = BitmapUtils.scaleBitmap(mask2, w, h);
        bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, mask2));

        final Bitmap cropped = cropBitmapWithMask(bitmap, mask2);
        bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, cropped));
    }else {
        bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, (Bitmap)null));
        bitmaps.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, (Bitmap)null));
    }

        return bitmaps;


    }


    private boolean checkAndReportDimen(String filePath) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
            return false;
        }

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        final int width = options.outWidth;
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        Logger.debug("original image dimen: %d x %d", width, height);

        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ImageDimenEvent(mImageUri, width, height));

        return (height > width);
    }


    private Bitmap cropBitmapWithMask(Bitmap original, Bitmap mask) {
        if (original == null
                || mask == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final int w = original.getWidth();
        final int h = original.getHeight();
        if (w <= 0 || h <= 0) {
            return null;
        }

        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cropped);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(null);

        return cropped;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromFile(String filePath,
                                              int reqWidth,
                                              int reqHeight) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
            return null;
        }

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }


}
```

Comment: Intents are intended for communication between Activities. There is no way to send information via an Intent to a non-activity class. You should use other ways of communication to send information to a "Non-Activity" class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the `button` id, if you want to do so, you have to change your method to this :

```
private void backToMain2(int button_id) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainSecond.this, SegmentBitmapsLoader.class);
    intent2.putExtra("button_id",button_id);
    startActivity(intent2);
}
```

And when you click to `button` do this :

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            backToMain2(R.id.button1);
        }
    });
```

But I do now know why you are doing `startActivity()`, `SegmentBitMapsLoader` it's not an `Activity` and `startActivity()` as documentatio says :

> Launch a new activity. You will not receive any information about when the activity exits. This implementation overrides the base version, providing information about the activity performing the launch. Because of this additional information, the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK launch flag is not required; if not specified, the new activity will be added to the task of the caller.

You have to think other way to comunicate your `MainSecond Activity` to that `SegmentBitmapsLoader.class`.

> when I tried to use getIntent().getStringExtra(); in the (SegmentBitmapsLoader.java) it gives me error because this class doesn't extend Activity what should I do ?

You could add on its constructor the `button id` of `Button` clicked, so you can do stuff with that, for example you could so something like :

```
SegmentBitmapsLoader segmentBitmapsLoader = new SegmentBitmapsLoader(this,YOUR_URI,YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
```

And then doing `segmentBitmapsLoader.` you can acces to its methods.

Your questions is quite unclear, so I tried my best to understand your problem and try to guide you.